# Deleting a part of a string between two strings

Tags: c#, xml, string

So, im writing a program, i have an xml file with attack moves in it and i wish to replace the damage values with my values, i have my values already, accompanied with a name, and example is

> "tackle|2d8"

now, in my xml file it goes as follows:

```
<Move>
    <Name>Steamroller</Name>
    <Type>Bug</Type>
    <Frequency>EOT</Frequency>
    <Accuracy>2</Accuracy>
    <Range>Melee</Range>
    <Damage>1d10+10</Damage>
    <Class>Physical</Class>
    <Targets>1 Target, Pass</Targets>
    <Effect>Steamroller Flinches the target on 15-20 during Accuracy Check. If the target is Small, Steamroller deals an additional 1d10.</Effect>
    <ContestType>Tough</ContestType>
    <Appeal>3d4</Appeal>
    <ContestEffect>No Effect</ContestEffect>
    <Special />
  </Move>
  <Move>
    <Name>String Shot</Name>
    <Type>Bug</Type>
    <Frequency>At-Will</Frequency>
    <Accuracy>3</Accuracy>
    <Range>6</Range>
    <Damage />
    <Class>None</Class>
    <Targets>1 Target, Column</Targets>
    <Effect>String Shot creates a Column 2-meters wide. All Legal Targets within the Column lower their Speed 1 Combat Stage. If a target is hit by String Shot 5 times within 5 rounds of combat, they are Trapped. If a target's Speed Combat Stage has already been lowered 6 times, String Shot Traps them.</Effect>
    <ContestType>Smart</ContestType>
    <Appeal>2d4</Appeal>
    <ContestEffect>Excitement</ContestEffect>
    <Special>Threaded</Special>
  </Move>
```

So basically i want to replace the text inbetween the `<Damage>` and `</Damage>` but i have no idea how to go about this, currently what i have is two Arrays, one has in it my moves with their damage, and the other is the Xml file moves split up (by using `string.Split("</Move>")`) then i loop through both like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < xmlMoves.Length; index++)
        {

            foreach (var move in myMovesArray)
            {
//myMoves.Split('|')[0] is the name of the move, 
    //i'm comparing that the move i am at in my Array is the same as the one in the Array of Xml Moves
                if (xmlMoves[index].Contains(myMoves.Split('|')[0])) 

                {
                    //Replace stuff here
                }
            }
        }
```

if anyone can help that would be great, thanks!!

Comment: You shouldn't have to use string manipulation for this - you can easily access the `<Damage>` element using Linq-to-Xml.

Comment: Do not treat an xml file as text file. Use one of the xml readers and manipulate it as xml. Plenty of examples online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!

As mentioned in comments you want to parse the xmlString as an actual XML object so you can easily access the elements. This uses XDocument so you'll need to add `using System.Xml.Linq;` to the top of your file.

```
private void XMltest()
{
    string filePath = @"path to your xml";
    string[] myMovesArray = new string[2] {"Steamroller|2d8", "String Shot|4d10"};

    // Add a root to your xml since it wasn't shown in your example
    // NOTE: Remove these next two lines if your xml string does indeed have a root. 
    string xmlFragments = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    string rootedXML = "<root>" + xmlFragments + "</root>";

    // load the xml
    XDocument xmlMoves = XDocument.Parse(rootedXML);

    // Loop through array and update associated element in xml with the new damage values
    foreach (var move in myMovesArray)
    {
        string moveName = move.Split('|')[0];
        string moveDamage = move.Split('|')[1];

        // Loop through xml and find the correct element by name
        foreach (XElement xmlMove in xmlMoves.Descendants("Move"))
        {
            if (xmlMove.Element("Name").Value == moveName)
            {
                xmlMove.Element("Damage").Value = moveDamage;
            }
        }
    }

    // Save back to xml file.
    xmlMoves.Save(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, don't do this with text manipulation. This is really easy using LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var move in doc.Descendants("Move"))
{
    if ((string) move.Element("Name") == "Steamroller")
    {
        var damage = move.Element("Damage");
        if (damage != null)
        {
            damage.Value = "2d8";
        }
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T5imjo) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regex replace with backward and forward lookahead:

- Backward: `(?<=(STR_BEFORE)))`
- Forward: `(?=(STR_AFTER))`

So, for example `(?<=(abc))def(?=(ghi))` would replace def only if preceded by abc and succeeded by ghi

Comment: Although the OP asked for the string manipulation... an XML based approach would be the logical and correct solution for this.

Comment: If they simply want to just replace the string, and don't need to do anything else to the XML, it seems overkill to parse anything.

Comment: I did only need to do this the once, i literally needed to update a text file once which i use for another program, and i though editing it text-based would be easier than spending a bunch of time learning how to use XML too